# Fetch csv files and filter using R

Tags: r, performance, csv, filter, tidyverse

Is there a faster way to fetch a bunch of csv files, merge them together (they all have the same structure) yet only keep those Values (a column) which are greater than 5?

The csv files will have thousands of rows each while typically fewer than 100 (per csv) will be greater than 5.

The working code I have is:

```
library(tidyverse)

filelocns <-"C:/Data/test/"

# get files list from folder
file.list <- list.files(path=filelocns, recursive=T,pattern='*.csv')  

# row bind the listed CSVs and filter for Values >= 5
rows_gt5 <- lapply(paste0(filelocns,file.list),read.csv) %>% 
    bind_rows() %>% 
    filter(Value>=5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try whether `read_csv` is suitable for you, i.e. change the line

```
rows_gt5 <- lapply(paste0(filelocns,file.list),read.csv) %>%
```

to

```
rows_gt5 <- lapply(paste0(filelocns,file.list),read_csv) %>%
```

In general it is faster than `read.csv`.
Have a look at the [docs](http://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_delim.html) for further details on how to use it.

Comment: much faster indeed!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would approach this:

```
# source dependencies
library(dplyr)

# declare path to desired directory
filelocns <-"C:/Data/test/"

# list all of the files within this directory
file.list <- list.files(path=filelocns
    ,pattern='\\.csv$'
    ,all.files = FALSE
    ,full.names = TRUE
    ,ignore.case = FALSE
)  

# apply the read_csv function to our list of files
row_gt5 <- ldply(file.list, read_csv) %>%

# and filter out values less than five
    filter(Values>=5)
```

You can replace the read_csv function with a custom function wrapper to re-format raw data on the fly before storing it into a master dataframe.
It sounds like read_csv is all you need to get going though.